# how to access the response headers using jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

```
Connection: keep-alive   
Content-Length: 2231  
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8  
Date: Thu, 13 Sep 2018 07:37:46 GMT  
ETag: W/"8b7-XOXhf04O/VM7yxWQ561PEgxRfz8"  
x-auth: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YjlhMGEyM2Q0NmI3YjFmYTQzNWI4YWIiLCJhY2Nlc3MiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNTM2ODI0MjY2fQ.SAufAzjP-6vkCoaCSSGKgXTjaP5prHKZ8uFCpZmjllE  
X-Powered-By: Express
```

In this headers I want to store the x-auth token in a variable so that I can further use it. How should I do it? Please help

Comment: Thanks for the edit Saumini Navaratnam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below code

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET/POST',
   url:'url',
   data: dataformat,
   success: function(data, status, req){
        alert(req.getResponseHeader('headername'));
   },
   error: function (req, status, error) {
        alert(req.getResponseHeader('headername'));
   }
  });
```

Comment: This code works but how should i store the value of  this req.getResponseHeader('headername') any solution?

Comment: I have a token value to store then should i accomplish it ?

Comment: You can store token in input type hidden.. or you can store token in localstorage as well

Comment: Thank you sir from the bottom of my heart I was struggling since 1 week.

Comment: Glad to help.  @maheshmaharana

Comment: @maheshmaharana can you please accept and voteup this answer, it will help other users it stuck in same kind of problem.

Comment: Actually i am new here . So i was unaware about the voteup. So I did now.

Comment: Thanks @maheshmaharana

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
myXMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if(this.readyState == this.HEADERS_RECEIVED) {
    var header= myXMLHttpRequest.getResponseHeader("x-auth");
  }
}
```

Comment: It says myXMLHttpRequest is not defined.

Comment: @maheshmaharana change the variable to the name of http request object you use.